# how to access service name from a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have below service running in my k8s pod. I want to access and ping service name "service-plt-mediator" from another pod. What needs to be added in manifest file of the pod so that the service name should be in /etc/host file and can be pinged from inside the pod?

```
/home/ravi>kubectl get svc | grep 
NAMESPACE     NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                           AGE
plt        service-plt-mediator     ClusterIP   10.108.188.147   <none>        4561/TCP,4562/TCP                 3h47m
```

Tried to add entry using "hostAlias" in manifest file, but it needs a static IP also. Which I can not as the service IP will change after reboot

Comment: You need to change absolutely nothing.  Kubernetes doesn't use the hard-to-manage `/etc/hosts` file but rather provides a DNS service; see for example [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).  Using ping(1) to send an ICMP ECHO packet is not an especially valuable task and I wouldn't bother trying it in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a mapping in `/etc/hosts`. Your pods `/etc/resolv.conf` is configured by `kubelet` to send DNS queries to CoreDNS service that is running in the cluster (You can see that default config in the pod spec as `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst`). The DNS response will be the `clusterIP` of the Service.

You can use `<service-name>.<namespace>` as the DNS request name in the other pod.

You can debug your DNS in the cluster as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).